# Initializing Singly Linked List Java

Tags: java, list, initialization, adt

I am trying to implement an abstract data type of NumList in class NumLinkedList as a singly linked list.

```
public class NumLinkedList implements NumList
{

Node head;
int nItem;

private class Node
{
    public Node next;
    public double value;
    public Node(double i, Node j)
    {
        value = i;
        next = j;

    }

}

public NumLinkedList()
{
    head = null;
    nItem = 0;

}
```

is my initialization and I am having trouble with the following methods.

```
public void print()
{
    Node currNode = head;
    while(currNode.next != null)
    {
        currNode = currNode.next;
        System.out.println(currNode.value);
    }

}

public int size()
{
    int size = 0;
    Node currNode = head;
    while(currNode.next != null)
    {
        currNode = currNode.next;
        size++;
        nItem++;

    }
    return size;

}

public void insert(int i, double value)
{
    if( i < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error. out of bounds.");
    }
    if ( i > size())
    {
        Node currNode = head;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        currNode.next = new Node(value,null);
    }

    if ( i <= size())
    {
        Node currNode = head;
        for(int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) // this moves CurrNode to the i-1th node
        {
            currNode = currNode.next;
        }
        currNode.next = new Node(value,currNode.next);
    }

    nItem++;
}
```

when I run my testing code,

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    NumLinkedList test;
    test = new NumLinkedList();

    //System.out.println("this is how many initial items the initialized list has");
    //System.out.println(test.size());
    test.insert(1, 0.1);
    System.out.println("have tried to insert value 0.1 @ position 1, that is the first element in list.");
    test.print();
    System.out.println("tried print(). did it work?");
    test.insert(4, -1);
```

I get an error in the

```
test.insert(1, 0.1);
```

, referring to

```
if ( i > size())
```

and

```
while(currNode.next != null)
```

as I failed initializing my array ADT as well, I believe that my list ADT is also mis-initialized. It's hard to find proper examples on Google, any references for ADT initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't in the initialization, which is fine, but in the methods themselves.

The problem is that you're initializing your `head` to `null`, but then, both in `print`and in `size`, you're doing `currNode = head`, which also makes it `null`, and then looping on `currNode.next`. That'll throw a `NullPointerException` right there. You need to go to all your methods and add special code for the limit case:

For `print`:

```
if ( head == null )
    return;
```

For `size`:

```
if ( head == null )
    return 0;
```

Alternatively, you can simply replace your entire `size` method with a simple `return nItem;` statement.

For `insert`:

```
if ( head == null )
{
    head = new Node(value,null);
    return;
}
```

As an aside, in your `insert`, you also need a `return` inside your first `if`, and you need to replace your third `if` with an `else`.

Comment: wait I don't understand why I need a (head == null);
this is the initial condition and a given, shouldn't I just check i values and ranges/limits on i values?

Comment: If `head == null` were a given, your list would always be empty. `head == null` holds right after the initialization, but only for as long as you don't set it to some other value on a correctly coded insert.